# how to find goal id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

If we had html code like this

```
<button onclick="teta()">click me !</button>
<br />
<div class="myclass">
<input type="text"  id="id1" />
</div>
```

how we can get this id without static use it ?
for example we can write number 100 in it with this code

```
document.getElementById('id1').value = 100;
```

and this is true

but with parent class and dynamic code for id how we can do this ?
i tried to do this with this code

```
function teta() {
    var myvar = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass').childNodes;
                for (var i = 0; i < myvar.length; i++) {
                    myvar[i].addEventListener('', function () {
                        document.getElementById(this.id(/^id/)).value = 100;
                    }, false);
}
```

but this is wrong

Comment: Why you pass event name as empty string?  Try addEventListener('click', ....

Comment: You know id needs to be unique on the page right? Having two elements with the same id is invalid HTML and will cause strange results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function teta() {
    var myvar = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0].childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < myvar.length; i++) {
        myvar[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
           this.value = 100;
        }, false);
   }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="teta()">click me !</button>
<br />
<div class="myclass">
<input type="text"  id="id1" />
</div>
```

When you are iterating through each element, there's no point fetching the element by id. You can simply use `this` keyword to reference the inputs. The `[0]` here is to select the first node with the specified classname.

```
function teta() {
    var myvar = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0].childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < myvar.length; i++) {
        myvar[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
           this.value = 100;
        }, false);
   }
}
```

**Update :**

[document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array. So we're using index `0` to select the first matching result.

Your input has a name `id1`. To get it's value, you can simply write :

```
var value = document.getElementById("id1").value;
```

Here, [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) will return you a reference of the input box and `.value` will return it's value.

Comment: Btw `getElementsByClassName` returns a nodeList. One must iterate through it or select an individual element first.

Comment: what is the meaning of [0]

Comment: and how can i get number in input box without click on this ?

Comment: @mrid this id is static but i want to define dynamic id like document.getElementById(this.id(/^id/)).value , but i think this is mistake , what is the true definition getelementbyid for dynamic id

Comment: @Dani what do yo mean by dynamic id ? Are you adding the elements dynamically ??

Comment: i want to get id if it has number before or after itself , for example id is : id1 or id2 or id1000 i want to automaticaly write number within it , your code can help me when i want to write number in static id like id1 , i tring use this code document.getElementById(id(/^id/)).value but i cannot write number overthere

Answer (score 0):

> getElementsByClassName return **collection** of element not element.
>   From W3:
>
> The getElementsByClassName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object.

So you can try:

> document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0].childNodes

or loop trough document.getElementsByClassName('myclass') if needed.

> And your problem is not clear. Is this snippet helps you?

```js
function teta(buttonEl) {
    var id = buttonEl.getAttribute('data-id');
    var value = buttonEl.getAttribute('data-value');
    document.getElementById('id'+id).value = value;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="teta(this)" data-id="1" data-value="100">click me 1!</button>
<br />
<button onclick="teta(this)" data-id="2" data-value="200">click me 2!</button>
<br />
<button onclick="teta(this)" data-id="3" data-value="300">click me 3!</button>

<br />
<br />

<div class="myclass">
  <input type="text"  id="id1" />
<br />
  <input type="text"  id="id2" />
<br />
  <input type="text"  id="id3" />
</div>
```

Comment: * `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of elements

Comment: Yes, technically (and slightly obtusely) it's not an array o_O

Comment: I have fixed it as a collection of elements

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection` ( an array like object ), you are not targeting an element of the returned collection.

You can actually simply use the `children` prop with `querySelector` and then look for elements with a `nodeName` of `'INPUT'`.

Here is an example.

```js
function onInputFocus (evt) {
  this.value = 100;
}

function teta() {
  var children = document.querySelector('.myclass').children;
  [].slice.call(children).forEach(function(child) {
    if (child.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
      child.addEventListener('focus', onInputFocus)
    }
  })
}
```

```css
input {
   display: block
}
```

```html
<button onclick="teta()">click me !</button>
<br />
<div class="myclass">
  <label for="">input 1</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <label for="">input 2</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <label for="">input 3</label>
  <input type="text" />
  <label for="">input 4</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: your code is realy good but unfortunately i should accept only one answer for my question , thanks ahead

Comment: i want to get id if it has number before or after itself , for example id is : id1 or id2 or id1000 i want to automaticaly write number in it ,  i try use this code document.getElementById(id(/^id/)).value but i cannot write number overthere